# Overlap Date Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I trying to select only those TNs which has bad data based on the dates in between Eff_date and End_Date. I am trying to filter out the bad data. This is what I have:

```
TN          EFF_DATE      END_DATE
3097402606  12/4/2007   1/23/2011 23:59
3097402606  12/4/2007   12/31/2099
4054631308  6/15/2005   2/25/2008 23:59
4054631308  5/9/2008    7/14/2009 23:59
4054631308  5/9/2008    12/31/2099
5745378900  4/10/2012   5/21/2012 23:59
5745378900  2/4/2016    12/31/2099
7062329778  12/16/2008  10/27/2009 23:59
7062329778  10/28/2009  11/10/2009 23:59
7062329778  10/28/2009  12/31/2099
```

But I need to pick only this data which is BAD. There is a relation between EFF_DATE and END_DATE.

```
  TN            EFF_DATE      END_DATE
 4054631308     6/15/2005     2/25/2008 23:59
 4054631308     5/9/2008      7/14/2009 23:59
 **4054631308       5/9/2008      12/31/2099** 

 7062329778     12/16/2008    10/27/2009 23:59
 7062329778     10/28/2009    11/10/2009 23:59
 **7062329778       10/28/2009    12/31/2099**
```

As you can see EFF_DATE is repeating itself for the TNs. Once the END_DATE is been confirmed 7/14/2009 for 4054631308 the EFF_DATE can't be 5/9/2008, either it can 7/15/2009 or it doesn't need to be there, but that something I need to show it to my team.
I just need to pick the data which looks like this so I can explain my though process to the team.

I have tried different ways in Oracle SQL but no success yet. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "has an overlap date in between `eff_date` and `end_date`"?  Can you please [edit] your question and include some more details?

Comment: Can you explain the rule again - why are some rows selected and some are not? You said "which has overlap date in between eff_date and end_date" - what does that mean? Look at your "desired output" - what overlap is there for the dates from the FIRST ROW and anything else? Also, from the input data, the first two rows show an overlap but you are not selecting them - why?

Comment: Although I don't fully understand your question yet, I feel like the result will involve the `LEAD` and `LAG` analytical functions, partitioning by `tn`.

Comment: you can write a function and pass each Tn to it to find if that TN has overlap or not. Then you can select from table where that function return true for each tn

Comment: Thank you for making an effort to clarify. Unfortunately, I am still confused. In your new formulation - what do you mean by "end_date has been confirmed"? How do you see that in the input data? And why is row #2 in your inputs not a "BAD DATA" row, whatever your rules?

Answer (score 1):

For overlaps of time periods, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.tn = t.tn and
                    t2.eff_date < t.end_date and
                    t2.end_date > t.eff_date
             );
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see, you want all TN rows, not just the ones with the overlaps.  In that case, one method uses `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.tn in (select t.tn
               from t
               where exists (select 1
                             from t t2
                             where t2.tn = t.tn and
                                   t2.eff_date < t.end_date and
                                   t2.end_date > t.eff_date
                 );
```

Comment: select t.*
from t
where t.tn in (select t.tn
               from t
               where exists (select 1
                             from t t2
                             where t2.tn = t.tn and
                                   t2.eff_date < t.end_date and
                                   t2.end_date > t.eff_date
                 ); and tn in ('3097402606')
when I put this good TN it still shows up, I was expecting to be return nothing but it still gave me the rows though.

Comment: select t.*
from t
where t.tn in (select t.tn
               from t
               where exists (select 1
                             from t t2
                             where t2.tn = t.tn and
                                   t2.eff_date < t.end_date and
                                   t2.end_date > t.eff_date
                 ); and tn in ('5745378900')
when I put this good TN it still shows up, I was expecting to be return nothing but it still gave me the rows though.